# How can i delete and rename a file in Android?

Tags: android, file, rename

Hello I have been looking for ways to delete or rename an specific file in the internal storage of the cellphone. Specifically my targets are the files in the waze folder, that are in the root folder of the internal storage. As I said, I look for more information about this but nothing works for me, so I think that my error might be in the path i'm using. Here is my code:

TO RENAME:

```
    file_Path = "/data/data/waze"
    File from      = new File(file_Path, "currentFileName");
    File to        = new File(file_Path, "newFilename");
    from.renameTo(to); //this method returns me False
```

TO DELETE:

```
file_Path ="/data/data/waze/file"
File file = new File(file_Path);
boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

I try a lot of ways to do this, but this is the one I think is near to get it. So If anyone of you could point me my mistake/s I would thank you! A hug from Costa Rica!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not have read or write access to files on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) other than your own app's files. You cannot rename or delete files from another app, such as Waze.

The exception is that on rooted devices, you can ask to fork processes with superuser privileges, and those processes would have device-wide read/write access.

Comment: that's very sad jaja! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

For completing @CommonsWare answer, you can check if the device is rooted, then do the methods or something else.

Here is an example,

**Taken from** : http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/01/android-requesting-root-access-in-your-app/

```
Process p; 
try { 
   // Preform su to get root privledges
   p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su"); 
   
   // Attempt to write a file to a root-only 
   DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream()); 
   os.writeBytes("echo \"Do I have root?\" >/system/sd/temporary.txt\n");
   
   // Close the terminal
   os.writeBytes("exit\n"); 
   os.flush(); 
   try { 
      p.waitFor(); 
           if (p.exitValue() != 255) { 
              // TODO Code to run on success
              toastMessage("root");
           } 
           else { 
               // TODO Code to run on unsuccessful
               toastMessage("not root");    
           } 
   } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
      // TODO Code to run in interrupted exception
       toastMessage("not root"); 
   } 
} catch (IOException e) { 
   // TODO Code to run in input/output exception
    toastMessage("not root"); 
}
```

Or you can take a look at :

> http://su.chainfire.eu/#how
>
> https://github.com/Chainfire/libsuperuser

and also, use the following permission in your manifest too:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER" />
```

Or a good example is available on Github:

https://github.com/mtsahakis/RootChecker